# Inverse a matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix-inverse

I want to inverse a matrix Q+1e-5*np.eye(d) (size d X d) and use the following code to get the  approximate result.

```
Q = X.dot(X.T) # X is a large sparse matrix, Q is singular
P = np.linalg.inv(Q+1e-5*np.eye(d))
```

But I got this:

```
P=[[ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
   ...,
  [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
  [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]]
```

Do anyone have any idea?

Comment: You want to invert a singular matrix?

Comment: You know that a singular matrix doesn't have an inverse, by definition, right?

Comment: (Do you mean you are trying to solve a system of simultaneous linear equations given by a singular matrix?)

Comment: I know it is not possible to inverse a singular matrix. But I don't think Q+1e-5*np.eye(d) can be singular too. I am just wondering why the result is NaN.

Answer (score 1):

A singular matrix, by definition, has no inverse. Based on this example it looks like the writers of `numpy` chose to give you an undefined result instead of throwing an error when you try to invert a matrix which cannot be inverted.